# MVVM+MEF : Parent View Model populate Children View Model using MEF

Tags: mvvm, mef

I've asked this question before but it was in general form so I couldn't get an answer so here I will ask about specific points:

As per the following code, I want re-write this code using MEF instead of using (new) operator but I faced the following issues for which I need answers:

1-How CountryViewModel (in the constructor) can create collection of child RegionViewModel that has argument constructor and populate it by Model objects? I tried using GetExportedValues<>() but no success because I can't pass arguments to the constructor and I can't use linq query to populate the RegionViewModel as shown in the code.

2-How RegionViewModel can load child View Model collection of StateViewModel in LoadChildren method
  using foreach block but also using MEF not new operator? I also tried to use GetExportedValues<>() but I can't pass parameters to the child view model

```
public class CountryViewModel
{
    readonly ReadOnlyCollection<RegionViewModel> _regions;
    public ReadOnlyCollection<RegionViewModel> Regions
    {
        get { return _regions; }
    }

    //---------------------------------------------------------
    public CountryViewModel(Region[] regions)
    {
        _regions = new ReadOnlyCollection<RegionViewModel>(
            (from region in regions
             select new RegionViewModel(region))
            .ToList());
    }

}

public class RegionViewModel : TreeViewItemViewModel
{
    readonly Region _region;

    public RegionViewModel(Region region) 
        : base(null, true)
    {
        _region = region;
    }

    public string RegionName
    {
        get { return _region.RegionName; }
    }

    protected override void LoadChildren()
    {
        foreach (State state in Database.GetStates(_region))
            base.Children.Add(new StateViewModel(state, this));
    }
}
```